# Loading multiple libraries simultaneously

Tags: r, function

I am trying to write a function to load several libraries at once. Through other forums and threads I have found that this works:

```
read_library <- function(...) {
  x <- c(...)
  invisible(lapply(x, library, character.only = TRUE))
}
```

However, this forces me to write my libraries between "", i.e.:

```
read_library("tidyverse",
         "readr",
         "infer",
         "modelr",
         "statip",
         "knitr",
         "rmdformats")
```

Which I would like to avoid. Is there anything I could add to my function that would eliminate this first world problem?

Comment: just ensure the function takes no parameters and then put all the libraries you want to be loaded within your function. eg `x<- c("tidyverse","readr")` and then just call `read_library()`

Comment: I kinda like the quotes but does this do what you want; `read_library = function(...){   y = as.list(match.call()[-1L]);   lapply(y, function(pkg) library(as.character(pkg), character.only=TRUE))  }`

Comment: is the issue with quotes or listing them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way could be using `alist` with `eval` and `substitute` like below:

```
read_library <- function(...) {
    obj <- eval(substitute(alist(...)))
    #print(obj)
    return(invisible(lapply(obj, function(x)library(toString(x), character.only=TRUE))))
}

read_library(gtools, ggplot2, tidyverse)
```

`alist` handles its arguments as if they described function arguments. So the values are not evaluated together with substitute it returns un-evaluated expression. Once we have the expression, we use eval to get a list of objects of class name, so that we can parse it as string in lapply.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `substitute` with `list` like :

```
read_library <- function(...) {
     invisible(lapply(substitute(list(...))[-1], function(x) 
                       library(deparse(x), character.only = TRUE)))
}

read_library(tidyverse,
             readr,
             infer,
             modelr,
             knitr, 
             scales)
```